# Cambiar de color un label, cuando se selecciona su input radio?

Tags: html, css

estoy intentando cambiar de color un label si se selecciona si input tipo radio, pero no lo he logrado, solo he podido hacer que cuando pase el mouse por encima cambie de color pero no que se mantenga.

**Codigo en CSS** aca esta el estiloq e coloque en las tarjetas, fondo naranja, y el estilo de hover para cuando paso el mouse por encima

```
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #F5E8E4;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #D1512D;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: flex;
    color: #D1512D;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.tarjeta-de-pet{
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #D1512D;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #F5E8E4;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: flex;
    color: #F5E8E4;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
```

**Codigo en HTML** aca esta como se definieron los label e input

```
                <label class="tarjeta-de-pet" for="firefox">
                    <p>Firefox </p>
                    <img src="./assets/dangerpets_pet_firefox.png" alt="Firefox ">
                </label>
                <input class="input-de-pet" type="radio" name="pets" id="firefox"/>
                <label class="tarjeta-de-pet" for="trebolclan">
                    <p>Trebolclan ☘️</p>
                    <img src="./assets/dangerpets_pet_trebolclan.png" alt="Trebolclan ☘️">
                </label>
                <input class="input-de-pet" type="radio" name="pets" id="trebolclan"/>
                <label class="tarjeta-de-pet" for="watermelon">
                    <p>Watermelon </p>
                    <img src="./assets/dangerpets_pet_watermelon.png" alt="Watermelon ">
                </label>
                <input class="input-de-pet" type="radio" name="pets" id="watermelon"/>
                <label class="tarjeta-de-pet" for="antpet">
                    <p>Antpet </p>
                    <img src="./assets/dangerpets_pet_antman.png" alt="Antpet ">
                </label>
                <input class="input-de-pet" type="radio" name="pets" id="antpet"/>
                <label class="tarjeta-de-pet" for="spiderpet">
                    <p>Spiderpet ☘️</p>
                    <img src="./assets/dangerpets_pet_spiderpet.png" alt="Spiderpet ☘️">
                </label>
                <input class="input-de-pet" type="radio" name="pets" id="spiderpet"/>
                <label class="tarjeta-de-pet" for="thorpet">
                    <p>Thorpet ☘️</p>
                    <img src="./assets/dangerpets_pet_thropet.png" alt="Thorpet ☘️">
                </label>
                <input class="input-de-pet" type="radio" name="pets" id="thorpet"/>
            </div>
```

**El problema es que cuando le doy click al label este no conserva el color blanco y vuelve a quedar naranjado**

[image: botones label]

[image: Cambio de color cuando paso el mouse encima]

Comment: Puedes colocar todo tus estilos por favor para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: El hover sólo te cambia el color cuando pasas por encima, no de forma permanente. ¿Usas Javascript en algún momento?

Comment: Falta código por ahí. Pégalo todo!

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es que el elemento se quede con el `:hover` activo debes utilizar otra instrucción de CSS llamada `:focus` de este modo cuando el usuario haga click el estilo seguirá activo en el elemento.

```
.tarjeta-de-pet:focus {
  /* tus estilos del hover aquí tambien*/
}
```

Te dejo una referencia con más información: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:focus

Answer (score 1):

Cuando trates de hacer interfases interactivas lo mejor y más sencillo es hacerlo mediante javascript:

```
<button onclick="cambiaColor()">Click</button>

<script>
function cambiaColor() {
  document.getElementById("labelColor").style.backgroundcolor = "red";
}
</script>
```